# Open connections to database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, npgsql

I have an old Winforms application, it works with PostgreSQL in RDS.
It used old npgsql provider.
But I have modified the app and replaced the old Npgsql with the newest one.
It works ok, 10 users work,  but sometimes I exec

```
select pg_stat_activity
```

and see about 30  connections. 
I do not use pooling explicitly.
What is pooling parameter values (use and max size) by default?
How to fix it?

Comment: Cross-posted as a github issue, with a response there: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2855

Comment: Yes, thanx Shay, sorry, this situation is real problem for the users, thats why I have asked.

Answer (score 0):

Shay Rojansky has answered in the  github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2855(see his comment here).

But anyway: it looks like if user does not use pool in the connection string the npgsql uses it by default.